# Get attribute info info from parameter of type extension methode ? any other appraoch?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, attributes, extension-methods

there's any way to get attribute info from parameter of type extension methode ?
For example :

I have an Attribute like this :

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
    public class MyAttribute: Attribute 
    {
        public MyAttribute(string _mystring)
        {
            myString= _mystring;
        }

        public string myString{ get; set; }
    }
```

So,I have a property like this :

```
  [MyAttribute("TestInt")]
        public int MyInt;
```

and an extension methode like this :

```
public static void Execute(ref this int t)
        {
          //Get Attribute info here
          Console.WriteLine(t);
        }
```

and I wanna use it like this

```
MyInt.Execute();
```

Can i get the Attribute info in the Execute methode ?

Comment: I don't think so ... the attribute is on your class field ... when you pass an `int` as a parameter you are passing a Value-**COPY** => there is no such attribute on your copied parameter `int`

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, there's any way when I pass the value of this inti get field info on it? or any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

An `int` of `ref int` is *just that value/reference* - it doesn't carry with it the metadata context to understand things like attributes.

The only way I can think of for conveying that would be "expressions"; consider:

```cs
var obj = new Foo { MyInt = 42 };
SomeUtil.Execute(() => obj.MyInt);
```

where `Execute` is:

```cs
static class SomeUtil
{
    public static void Execute(Expression<Func<int>> t)
    {
        // investigate the attributes (only supports very simple scenarios currently)
        if (t.Body is MemberExpression me)
        {
            foreach (var attrib in me.Member.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(attrib.myString);
            }
        }

        // show the value
        Console.WriteLine(t.Compile()());
    }
}
```

This will *work*, but is very inefficient - it involves building an expression tree at the call-site each time, and then investigating that expression tree. Plus it also materializes the attribute instances each time. There are scenarios where this might be OK, but in the general case: definitely worth avoiding.

Comment: @ there's no other way to do this?
I need the Class name and the field name when I execute an extension method

Comment: @Davanci no, that's not a thing; the closest I can think of is `CallerArgumentExpression` etc, but that doesn't give you exactly what you want

Comment: yep CallerArgumentExpression don't give me what i want exactly :/